# Drupal permission table

Tags: php, drupal, database-design

If u have seen drupal permission table, that is like

structure 1

```
pid rid    perm                   tid
1    1   view f1, edit f2          0
2    2   view f1                   0
```

what is good with  structure1?

why drupal doesn't use this structure?

```
table1

    fid      name
    1      view f1
    2      edit f2

table2

pid  rid  fid
1     1    1
2     1    2
3     2    1
```

Comment: That's strange question. Anyway, I believe since it was developed by thousands of developers, then there's a reason for that.

Comment: In Drupal 7 it's much simpler. Table `role_permission` with fields `rid`, `permission` and `module`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you'd organise the data this way is due to the access pattern (how you use the data). Short answer - if you access your data only in one way, structure will be quicker. How much quicker? For the examples given it'll be trivial, maybe a few milliseconds saved at the database. If you went to structure 2 and still had less than 10,000 rows the performance difference would generally be trivial too.

The performance difference would become more significant when structure 1 had say 100,000 rows, while structure 2 required say 1,000,000 rows to store the same data. Then, depending on the complexity of your query and number of rows returned you would probably notice query execution time differences of hundreds of milliseconds to a second.

Lets look at why, take he following query:

```
 SELECT permission
 FROM perm 
 WHERE role = 1
```

### Advantages of structure 1:

A single row per role, stored in a single location on disk is returned. Disk seek time is reduced.

### Disadvantages of structure 1:

What if we want to find all roles which have edit permissions? That's a bit tricky, we (or the database) needs to process the records - which is CPU intensive. So that's a major downside, but ... If we're never accessing the data this way, or we access it this way very infrequently, and willing to live with the cost then that does not matter.

### Advantages of structure 2:

Because the data is normalized it is easy to find all permissions that belong to a role, or all roles that have a permission. It is a much more flexible structure.

### Disadvantages of structure 2:

Given the second structure, the records that make up the permissions for each role are potentially stored in different locations on disk. This means for very large tables, the performance will be worse than structure 1.

Conclusion:
Structure 1 was probably chosen to provide (very slightly) better performance given of how the data is used. It is a little more complex (hence this question about why this design decision was made). Drupal 7, likely went with structure 2 because it is simpler and the performance difference negligible in the common case.